# Changing navbar background color on scroll not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a site locally using Local by Flywheel. I am trying to get the navbar to go from transparent to a color on scroll. I've tried the following but it does not work. I check the console and it does not show any errors. Here's my html for the navbar

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="100" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
      <div id="home">
   <!-- Home/Header Navigation Section -->
    <nav class="navbar bg-light navbar-light  navbar-expand-md fixed-top" >
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="/img/logo.png" class="img-fluid logo" alt="Seacoast Web Development" title="Seacoast Web Development">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

and I'm using this javascipt to add the class 'scrolled'

```js
<script>
$(function () {
                var header = $(".navbar");

                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (scroll >= 50) {
                        header.addClass("scrolled");
                    } else {
                        header.removeClass("scrolled");
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

and here's the css for the navbar and the class 'scrolled'

```css
.navbar{
    background: transparent!important;
    transition:500ms ease;
}
.scrolled {
  background: rgba(247, 245, 245, 0.7)!important;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Your current code seems to be working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/utjbw8a6/7/

Comment: Can you open the elements inspector and see if the scrolled class is getting added to the .navbar element? If it does, then it probably means you have a CSS conflict, some other rule might be setting the background color. But if it doesn't, means your Javascript is not working

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it. Could it be the placement of the code on my html page with the bootstrap links?

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function () {
                var header = $(".navbar");

                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (scroll >= 50) {
                        header.addClass("scrolled");
                    } else {
                        header.removeClass("scrolled");
                    }
                });
            });
</script>`

Comment: And where's that? in the head? If it's in the head try to put it at the end of the body

Comment: Nicolas Castellanos I do not see the scrolled class added to navbar. Strange because there's no error in the console. I will check for conflicts on the background color.

Comment: the script is before the closing <body> tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had:

```
height: 100%; width: 100%; in the <body> tag
```

I don't know why that affected it but when I removed it, the menu changed color on scroll. Can anyone explain?

Comment: When you post something like this, it's a good practice to use JSfiddle or CodePen to show it as AndrewL64 did - https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/utjbw8a6/7/.  That might solve the issue even before posting here.

I tried modifying Andrew's code by adding height and width to be 100%, but it didn't break anything.